# Не могу принять ajax ответ от сервера

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть такой код

```
$.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        cache:false,
        data : {action: 'get_refs', curr_count: $('#getMoreRefs').attr('data-curr'), search_addon: $('#refsContainer').attr('data-search')},
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Не верный формат json, ключи и строковые значения должны быть заключены в двойные ковычки.')
        },
                    success:function(data) {


                        var html = new EJS({ext : '.html', url : '/about/otzyvu/reviews_line.html'}).render({data : data});
                        $('#moreRefs').html(html);
                        $('#moreRefs').show(300);
                        $('#moreRefs').attr('id', 'moreRefs_prev');
                        $('#moreRefs').hide();
                        $('#getMoreRefs').attr('data-curr', parseInt($('#getMoreRefs').attr('data-curr'))+3);
                        var curr = parseInt($('#getMoreRefs').attr('data-curr'));
                        var all = parseInt($('#refsContainer').attr('data-all'));
                        if (curr < all) {
                                $('#refsContainer').append('<div id="moreRefs" />');
                        } else {
                                $('#getMoreRefs').hide();
                        }
                    }
```

В ответ приходит такой массив

```
string(10) 1443566777 refsData: [{absnum: "1207", alias: "Roman Razrobotchik-1207", title: "Роман Разробот....
```

Из-за этого таймштампа спереди я не могу разпарсить ответ от сервера

вот код ответа сервера

```
echo json_encode(array('refsData'=>$articles_reviews));
```

Как убрать этот таймстамп, при этом кеш в аджаксе отключен...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по приведенному вами ответу сервера, что-то выводит данные **перед**

```
echo json_encode(array('refsData'=>$articles_reviews));
```

Вы не предоставили PHP код, поэтому я могу только порекомендовать искать вхождения `var_dump` и `echo` выше по коду.